# how to repeat a phrase or single character n-times to fill the container width with it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On a html page with parent div with a fixed width (e. g. 300px). As a child of it I got multiple div container which each of them contains one anchor. So, the structure is something like this:

```
<div class="tsstatus">
    <div class="tsstatusItem tsstatusServer">
        <!-- [...] -->
        <div class="tsstatusItem">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="image.png">Upload/Download
                <div class="tsstatusFlags">
                    <img src="image.png">
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [...] -->
    <div class="tsstatusItem *spacer">
    <a href="#" title="Wau [43]">
        <img src="image.png" alt="image.png">Wau
        <div class="tsstatusFlags">
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css to it:

```
.tsstatus, .tsstatuserror {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
}

.tsstatus, .tsstatus *, .tsstatuserror {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.tsstatus label {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.tsstatusItem a {
    color: #000000;
}

.tsstatusItem a:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #000099;
}

.tsstatuserror {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.tsstatus, .tsstatus * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tsstatus {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tsstatus label {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

.tsstatusItem {
    margin-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align: left;
}

.tsstatusItem a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tsstatusItem img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.tsstatusFlags {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.tsstatusServer {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.tsstatusItem.cspacer {
    text-align: center;
}

.tsstatusItem.rspacer {
    text-align: right;
}

.tsstatusItem.lspacer {
    text-align: left;
}
```

I want to repeat the characters inside the anchor to fill parent width. So, in this case repeat "phrase" until 300px is reached.

I try to do it with JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $elem;
    var iFontSize = 0;
    var iFullWidth = 0;
    var iIterations = 0;
    var sText = "";
    $(".item.repeat").each(
        function(index, value) {
            $elem = $(value).find("a").first();
            $elem.text($elem.text().trim());
            iFontSize = $elem.css("font-size");
            iFontSize = parseInt(iFontSize.substr(0, iFontSize.indexOf("px")));
            iFullWidth = $(value).innerWidth();
            // 1st Method
            //iIterations = parseInt(iFullWidth / (iFontSize * $elem.text().length));
            // 2nd Method
            iIterations = parseInt(iFullWidth / $elem.innerWidth());
            for (var i = 0; i < iIterations; i++) {
                sText += $elem.text();
            }
            $elem.text(sText);
        }
    );
});
```

Neither the first or second method worked for me. Also, for some strange reason, `$(value).width()` was not the excepted value of 300px. Instead I think it is the window width, because it was something like 1904px.

Also my first method assumes to have a monoscaped font. Maybe not the best way for a browser default font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class definition of `*spacer` is invalid. `*` is a reserved character in CSS and cannot be used in class names. I removed it from my solution.

The spacer element had property `display: block` which makes it hard to size its content. Block elements inherently take the full width of the parent making it hard to assess the joint size of the image and filler text. I changed it to `display: inline-block`. Now we can easily figure out the amount of space to fill.

To track the size of one unit of the filler text I created a `<span>` around the word `Wau`. This allows me to accurately measure the size of this guy. Now I know how many times to repeat it in order to fill the space. JS has new calculations to run this thing.

See attached js fiddle and code.

https://jsfiddle.net/rc4qyuzc/1/

### HTML (removed * from class name)

```
<div class="tsstatus">
    <div class="tsstatusItem tsstatusServer">
        <!-- [...] -->
        <div class="tsstatusItem">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="image.png">Upload/Download
                <div class="tsstatusFlags">
                    <img src="image.png">
                </div>
            </a>
            <!-- -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [...] -->
    <div class="tsstatusItem spacer">
    <a href="#" title="Wau [43]">
        <img src="image.png" alt="image.png">
        <span class="spacer-text">Wau</span>
        <div class="tsstatusFlags">
        </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS (changed filler div to inline-block)

```
.tsstatus, .tsstatuserror {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 300px;
}

.tsstatus, .tsstatus *, .tsstatuserror {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.tsstatus label {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

.tsstatusItem a {
    color: #000000;
}

.tsstatusItem a:hover {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    color: #000099;
}

.tsstatuserror {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.tsstatus, .tsstatus * {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.tsstatus {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tsstatus label {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 0;
}

.tsstatusItem {
    margin-left: 16px;
    position: relative;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-align: left;
}

.tsstatusItem a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tsstatusItem img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

.tsstatusFlags {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.tsstatusServer {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.tsstatusItem.cspacer {
    text-align: center;
}

.tsstatusItem.rspacer {
    text-align: right;
}

.tsstatusItem.lspacer {
    text-align: left;
}

.tsstatusItem.spacer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

### JS (new calculations)

```
$(document).ready(function doReady() {
    var $elem;
    var iFontSize = 0;
    var iFullWidth = 0;
    var iIterations = 0;
    var sText = "";

    $(".tsstatusItem.spacer").each(
        function(index, value) {
            var $spacer_elem = $(value).find(".spacer-text").first();
            var width_available = $(".tsstatus").innerWidth() - $(value).innerWidth();
            var unit_filler_width = $spacer_elem.innerWidth();
            var times_to_fill = Math.floor(width_available/unit_filler_width);
            var unit_filler_text = $spacer_elem.text();
            var new_filler_text = unit_filler_text;
            for (var i = 0; i < times_to_fill; i++) {
                new_filler_text += unit_filler_text;
            }
            $spacer_elem.text(new_filler_text)
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. But you should really do `$(value).find(".spacer-text").first()` to avoid operating on array of jQuery objects. This will not happen in my case, but it's better code style. With this and `Math.floor(width_available/unit_filler_width) - 1` it really does job as I tried so far in your fiddle.

Comment: Updated. Happy to help. Enjoy!

Comment: I now know why it is rendered one more iteration as needed: You preinitialize the variable with the to repeated string first before you start the loop. That's one too much. Sorry, I also did not see it first...

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do what you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $().ready(function() {
      // Process items to be repeated
      $('.item.repeat a').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        var text = $this.text();

        // Remove these comments if spaces are needed
        /*text += ' ';
        $this.html($this.text()+'&nbsp;');*/

        var width = $this.outerWidth();
        var parentWidth = $this.parent('div').outerWidth();

        var numReps = Math.floor(parentWidth / width);

        $this.html(text.repeat(numReps));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper" style="width:300px;">
    <div class="item repeat">
      <a href="#">phrase</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="#">phrase</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item repeat">
      <a href="#">phrase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you need spaces between phrases, you can comment out the section that appends them.

Comment: thanks, that helped me a bit. It is real strange, sometimes he got a width from 1904px. But this happens only sometimes. May you give me a solution without whitespaces? I don´t need it. Also, my real identifier is `.tsstatusItem.\\*spacer`. Maybe it´s because of the multiply point in selector. I tested it on Opera and IE.

Comment: I've simplified the code. You don't need the off screen element unless you're attempting to get the text from a block element, which will fill the whole screen. Also, I changed the code so that there are no spaces between phrases, but there is code that is commented out that will do it. With respect to the different attributes in your real code, you'd need to replace my selectors with ones that will work for your code. If I change the code without seeing what you've done, it will probably be incorrect.

Comment: it does also not work. It prints it out too often. Much too often.

Comment: Could you please provide the initial text in the tag that is problematic?

Comment: I edited my original entry. Please see it for details. There you may find all related code to that problem.